# Different layout in landscape using Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I would like to use a different layout when my app rotates to landscape, see the following images: Portrait:

[image: Portrait]

Landscape:

[image: Landscape]

The blue boxes represent `UITextFields`.

What is the simplest method of rearranging them when rotating the device into landscape while still using Autolayout?

Comment: You need to add constraints programmatically

Comment: Could you post an example as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add separate constraints for both landscape/portrait orientation. See the following example it will help you. Here i have added constraints for one textfield only.

```
textfld1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [textfld1 removeConstraints:textfld1.constraints];
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

        //You can use either center horizontally or Leading
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textfld1
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:234.0]];

        //        // Center horizontally
        //        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textfld1
        //                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
        //                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
        //                                                                 toItem:self.view
        //                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
        //                                                             multiplier:1.0
        //                                                               constant:0.0]];

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textfld1
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:100.0]];


    }else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textfld1
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:120.0]];

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textfld1
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:140.0]];

    }

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textfld1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:nil
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:30]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textfld1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:nil
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:300]];

}
```

Comment: is there a way to add constraints for landscape mode in interface builder?

Comment: You can use IBoutlet-NSLayoutConstraints for your constraints in interface builder.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I was trying to ask if there's a way to add separate constraints for portrait and landscape mode, I know on android you are able define different layouts by naming the landscape layout file as "xxx-land", I am just wondering if there's any equivalent on iOS.